# wxWidgets add widgets (in a sizer) from bottom left instead of top left?

Tags: c++, position, wxwidgets, sizer

I want to add a *varying* amount of 2d squares on the bottom of a panel, whose widgets are inside a box sizer.

I made a Square class widget, that takes in a position, size, and color, and made 3 instances of it that I've added to the box sizer.

The problem is, they are placed from top left, instead of bottom left, how I would like.

**Square.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <wx/wx.h>

class Square : public wxWindow
{
    wxPoint position;
    wxSize size;
    wxBrush brushColor;

public:
    Square(wxPanel* parent, wxPoint rectPosition, wxSize rectSize, wxColour rectColor);

    void PaintEvent(wxPaintEvent& evt);
    void Draw(wxDC& dc);

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};
```

**Square.cpp**

```
#include "Square.h"

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(Square, wxPanel)
EVT_PAINT(Square::PaintEvent)
END_EVENT_TABLE()


Square::Square(wxPanel* parent, wxPoint position, wxSize size, wxColour color) : wxWindow(parent, wxID_ANY)
{
    this->position = position;
    this->size = size;
    this->brushColor = wxBrush(color);
}

void Square::PaintEvent(wxPaintEvent& evt)
{
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    Draw(dc);
}

void Square::Draw(wxDC& dc)
{
    dc.SetBrush(brushColor);
    dc.DrawRectangle(position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y);   
}
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "Square.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(const wxString& title) : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    wxBoxSizer* mainSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxPanel* sidePanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);
    wxPanel* largePanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);

    mainSizer->Add(sidePanel, 1, wxEXPAND | wxLEFT | wxTOP | wxBOTTOM, 5);
    mainSizer->Add(largePanel, 7, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);

    this->SetSizerAndFit(mainSizer);
    


    wxBoxSizer* squareSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    Square* red_square = new Square(largePanel, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(20, 20), wxColour(255, 0, 0));
    Square* green_square = new Square(largePanel, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(20, 20), wxColour(0, 255, 0));
    Square* blue_square = new Square(largePanel, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(20, 20), wxColour(0, 0, 255));

    squareSizer->Add(red_square, 1, wxEXPAND);
    squareSizer->Add(green_square, 1, wxEXPAND);
    squareSizer->Add(blue_square, 1, wxEXPAND);

    largePanel->SetSizerAndFit(squareSizer);
}
```

Comment: you should probably use [wxFormBuilder](https://github.com/wxFormBuilder/wxFormBuilder) to create the shape you want before you attempt to do that in code.

Comment: @zoinkers, what difference does it make? It is you who adds them not the user or a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using sizers, to align a window (or control) to the bottom of its parent you must tell so to the proper sizer (the one that calculates the layout of that parent.

```
squareSizer->Add(red_square, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALIGN_BOTTOM);
```

But using `wxEXPAND` with a wxHORIZONTAL sizer means that the window will take all *vertical* available space. So, the align-bottom will have no effect. It makes sense when the height (likely fixed, not expandable) of the window is less than the height of the parent where it's layed out.

Perhaps you want some vertical space between the rectangle (at bottom) and its parent panel top border.

If you want this space to be fixed you can use a border

```
squareSizer->Add(red_square, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALIGN_BOTTOM | wxTOP, 25); //border 25 pixels tall
```

If you want this space to be expandable then you must use another wxBoxSizer that contains a AddStretchSpacer before adding the window:

```
wxBoxSizer* verSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
verSizer->AddStretchSpacer(1);
verSizer->Add(red_square, 1, wxEXPAND);
squareSizer->Add(verSizer, 1, wxEXPAND);
```

And if you want to give 70% to the spacer and 30% to the bottom window use two proportion values:

```
verSizer->AddStretchSpacer(70);
verSizer->Add(red_square, 30, wxEXPAND);
```

All of this can be found in the docs:

https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_sizer.html

https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_box_sizer.html

Finally, consider using [wxSizerFlags](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_sizer_flags.html) instead of so many little clear parameters at Add() member.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to figure out a solution! However, maybe I wasn't clear in my initial question, but I want the squares to go from *left* to *right*, just like the sizer in the code above does. BUT placed on the bottom of the panel, instead of the top. Your code seems to place them bottom left panel yes, but right on top of each other?

Comment: The trick of using a second wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL) must be done for each of the three squares. Or instead, you can use a wxBS(V) that contains a Spacer and a wxBS(H) for the tree squares. This other option makes all three squares with same vertical size.

Comment: Thank you, but I found another way, catch a resize event and draw them from panelSize.y - squareSize.y instead of wxDefaultPosition,

Comment: @zoinkers Yeah, that's another way. But the day you use controls, fonts or images, rather than a colored square, you better use sizers.